# How to upload/copy file to a folder in Angularjs 4 using php as backend

Tags: php, angular

Am very new to angularjs. Am building a form which contains an image upload with angularjs 4. I do get other value of my form text input, my problem or where i find it confusing is to get the file path or copy it to a folder(ie. upload to a folder) which i have given. I will so much appreciate if i can get a breakdown on this, as all i have seen online are for angularjs 1 and 2 which to me are quit different(in structure).

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="EmpForm" (ngSubmit) = "OnSubmit(EmpForm.value)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empName" formControlName="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Profile Picture</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image" #EmpImage formControlName="EmpImage" accept="image/*"  file-input="files">
            </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!EmpForm.valid">SUBMIT</button> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormsubmitService } from './formsubmit.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      EmpForm: FormGroup;
      EmpImageFile: File;
      @ViewChild('EmpImage') Emp_Image;
      constructor(private  fb: FormBuilder, private fbservice: FormsubmitService) {
        this.EmpForm = this.fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'EmpImage': [''] /* tried using Validators.required here but it stile return invalid when a file is selected*/
        });
      }

     OnSubmit(value) {
        const File = this.Emp_Image.nativeElement;
          if (File.files && File.files[0]) {
              this.EmpImageFile = File.files[0];
          }
          const EmpImageUploadFile: File = this.EmpImageFile;

          const formData: FormData = new FormData();
          formData.append('name', value.name);
          formData.append('EmpImage', EmpImageUploadFile, EmpImageUploadFile.name);

          this.fbservice.submitData(formData).subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );
      }
    }

formSubmitService

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';


    @Injectable()
    export class FormsubmitService {

      constructor(private http: Http) { }

      submitData(formGroup) {
        const URL = 'http://localhost:80/angularfileupload/angularfileupload.php';
        const Res = this.http.post(URL, formGroup).map(res => res.json());
        return Res;
      }
    }
```

angularfileupload.php

```
   <?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $image = $_FILES["image"];

    print_r($name);
    print_r($image);

    ?>
```

// response of print_r

```
ChineduArray
(
    [name] => 2go_1036207947.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php58BD.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 5252
)
```

Here is where i find it hard to get. I can get the file path nor it octet value of the image.

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your post and add code sample.

Comment: I just did. i get other formdata but can figure out how to move the file(image) to a specified folder and send it's path to my serve(php)

Comment: I've never did that with PHP but check this link  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Well my problem is how do I get the file which is been selected to be uploaded(and copied to a folder ) and it new path send to my backend.. even if it not php. I do get other form input value(text) but can't figure out how to do that of the file.

Comment: Try giving a name attribute to the input where you select file. Use this name in your PHP code to retrieve the file : « $_FILES["fileToUpload"] ». Check also tne enctype attribute of the form : enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Check also this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521733/jquery-formdata-sends-an-empty-image

Comment: Update the code in your sample, that will be easier to follow your changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $image = $_FILES["image"]['name'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($image);

    $image_tmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $uploadOk = 1;

    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($image_tmp);
    if($check !== false) {
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_file);
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
?>
```

The image is actually located in a 
[tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php58BD.tmp 
which i have to process using 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]['name'];);
Then move it to the folder
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_file);